# How do you store text file data into bash script variables?

Tags: bash, variables, storage, git-bash

I have bash script that need to get data from another file called Node01.pc and assign those values into a variables in my script.
For example.

- lineOne = 192.168.0.99
- lineTwo = 2
- lineThree = 70
- ect

Node01.pc contains:

```
192.168.0.99
2
70
16
80
4
4
100
4
```

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Easy way is to read the lines into an array with the `mapfile` built-in.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about

```
targets=($(cat Node01.pc))
echo "${targets[0]}"
echo "${targets[1]}"
```

EDIT: as mention by Shawn this does not work for lines with spaces and blobs, empty lines - check https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: Consider accepting the answer (check sign under voting arrows)

Comment: Bad idea. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor for why.